# I wan to replace NA values with median of a column which are of numeric type in Rstudio

Tags: r

Here is what I have done, but with this solution I have new data frame which has numeric columns only but I want to keep my original data frame.

```r
data_without_na <- select_if(new_data,is.numeric)
data_without_na[] <- lapply(
  data_without_na,
  function(data_without_na) {
    data_without_na[is.na(data_without_na)] <- median(data_without_na, na.rm = TRUE)
    data_without_na
})
```

This is what my code is but I would prefer to perform the same operation on my original data frame. The idea is to get the index of columns which are of numeric data type, `ind <- which(sapply(new_data, is.numeric))` and get the column number to perform operation on my original data frame, but it's giving me an error

Comment: data_without_na <- select_if(new_data,is.numeric)
data_without_na[] <- lapply(data_without_na, function(data_without_na) { 
  data_without_na[is.na(data_without_na)] <- 
    median(data_without_na, na.rm = TRUE)
  data_without_na
}) This is what my code is but i am trying to perform same operation on my original data frame.  Idea is to get the index of columns which are of numeric data type , ind <-   which(sapply(new_data, is.numeric))      Than with these i can get the column number to perform operation on my original data frame, but it's giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

Simulate a dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame("char1" = sample(letters,100, replace = T),
                "char2" = sample(letters,100, replace = T),
                "numeric1" = sample(c(NA,seq(1,50,2.5)),100, replace = T),
                "numeric2" = sample(c(NA,seq(1,50,2.5)),100, replace = T))
```

```
d %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ifelse(is.na(.x),median(.x, na.rm = T),.x))
```

We take this data frame and mutate all columns which are numeric. "~" defines an anonymous function and ".x" stands for the variable/column.

Comment: i have tried it but it did not work.      for(i in 1:21){
new_data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric(new_data[i]), ifelse(is.na(new_data[i]),
                                median(new_data[i], na.rm = T),new_data[i]))
}gives me an error  `.p` is invalid.

Comment: for(i in 1:21){
  new_data %>% mutate_if(new_data[i],is.numeric) %>%
      new_data[is.na(new_data[,i]), i] <- 
        median(median(new_data[,i], na.rm = TRUE))
} I have tried this loop as well but the problem is wth median calculation. IT's giving an error that data should be numeric. it's not taking na.rm=T

Comment: Date Minimum temperature Maximum temperature Rainfall (mm) Direction of maximum wind gust  Speed of maximum wind gust (km/h) Time of maximum wind gust 9am Temperature 9am relative humidity (%) 9am cloud amount (oktas)
01-06-19 -0.7 15.2 0.2 S 30 13:23 4 99 
02-06-19 -1.6 15.7 0 NNW 30 14:08 4.2 90 
03-06-19 2.9 11.4 0.4 S 57 23:07 7.6 87 8
04-06-19 4.4 11.4 3.6 S 69 6:05 6.5 67 2
05-06-19 3.3 12.3 0 S 46 0:04 7.8 63 1
06-06-19 -3.9 14.6 0 W 19 16:08 1.6 95 
07-06-19 -1.3 17 0.2 SE 17 4:15 5.5 87 
08-06-19 -0.1 11.2 0 NNW 20 15:50 4.1 99 8
09-06-19 0.6 16 0 NW 28 15:57 4.6 100 8
Data

Comment: You don't need to index the dataframe by column (e.g. d[,i]) Just replace d with your dataframe. If it still doesnt work please provide some data for me to look at :)